# How to generate a 3-digit random number in xCode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, iphone-developer-program

The thing is that I need use a code like this, but it doesn't work with `char` variable. Can you  help me to write the code, or show how we can do it with an array?

Code:

```
char numeroMaquina[0] = arc4random() % 9;

switch(numeroMaquina[0]) {
        case 0:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 1;

            break;
        case 1:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 2;

            break;
        case 2:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 3;

            break;
        case 3:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 4;

            break;
        case 4:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 5;

            break;
        case 5:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 6;

            break;
        case 6:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 7;

            break;
        case 7:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 8;

            break;
        case 8:
            numeroMaquina[0] = 9;

            break;
    }

    int numeroMaquina2 = arc4random() % 9;
    switch(numeroMaquina2) {
        case 0:
            numeroMaquina2 = 1;

            break;
        case 1:
            numeroMaquina2 = 2;

            break;
        case 2:
            numeroMaquina2 = 3;

            break;
        case 3:
            numeroMaquina2 = 4;

            break;
        case 4:
            numeroMaquina2 = 5;

            break;
        case 5:
            numeroMaquina2 = 6;

            break;
        case 6:
            numeroMaquina2 = 7;

            break;
        case 7:
            numeroMaquina2 = 8;

            break;
        case 8:
            numeroMaquina2 = 9;

            break;
    }


    int numeroMaquina3 = arc4random() % 9;
    switch(numeroMaquina3) {
        case 0:
            numeroMaquina3 = 1;

            break;
        case 1:
            numeroMaquina3 = 2;

            break;
        case 2:
            numeroMaquina3 = 3;

            break;
        case 3:
            numeroMaquina3 = 4;

            break;
        case 4:
            numeroMaquina3 = 5;

            break;
        case 5:
            numeroMaquina3 = 6;

            break;
        case 6:
            numeroMaquina3 = 7;

            break;
        case 7:
            numeroMaquina3 = 8;

            break;
        case 8:
            numeroMaquina3 = 9;

            break;
    }
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that you just want a number between 1 and 9, instead of 0 and 8? If so, then to do `numeroMaquina[0]=numeroMaquina[0]+1`

Answer (score 5):

This looks like code where somebody was being paid by the word. Altogether, you code seems to work out about equivalent to:

```
char NumeroMaquina[3];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
   NumerMaquina[i] = arc4random() % 9 + 1;
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe you really want it to be

```
NumeroMaquina[i] = arc4random() % 9 + '1';
```

So each element in the array would be a printable digit instead?

If (as the title suggests) you just want a three-digit random number, it's probably easier to use something like:

```
int number = arc4random() % 1000;
```

Edit: To keep from getting 0, you'd use:

```
int number = arc4random() % 999 + 1;
```

...and if you want it in a string of characters, you can convert that with `sprintf` (for one example):

```
char as_string[4];

sprintf(as_string, "%3d", number);
```

Comment: I prefer your answer so I've deleted mine, plus it's 1AM in the morning and I'm knackered so I'm off to bed

Comment: yes i like a three-digit number but i dont like if it have a "0".

Answer (score 1):

```
int myNumber = arc4Random()%899 + 100;
```

This will give you a random number between 100 and 999.

Answer (score 0):

I think the iPhone supports C++11/libc++, so:

If you want 3 non-zero digits you can do:

```
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937 engine(seed);

    char digits[4] = {};
    std::generate(std::begin(digits),std::end(digits)-1,
      std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<char>('1','9'),std::ref(engine)));
}
```

Or maybe

```
int n = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,9*9*9-1)(engine); // 3 digit number in base 9
char digits[4] = {n/9/9%9 + '1',n/9%9 + '1', n%9 + '1'}; // don't use '0' as a digit symbol
```